# How "closed" is related to English language & usage?

Tags: discussion

My basic question is closed. I wonder what kind of questions are considered non-basic. Then I browse the "Questions" and find most of the questions are about what kind of questions should be closed. My question is :

How "closed" is related to English language & usage?

Comment: Can you try to rephrase your question? I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Probably your question was of no academic/scientific interest. This site is for *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.* If you're none of these it's unlikely your question will be advanced enough. You may be interested in supporting the proposed site "English for Language Learners", http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners where the requirements will be much lower.

Comment: I think maybe you were browsing the [meta questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions), which discuss the ELU site in general. To get back to questions about English Language and Usage, you'd need to go back to the [main site](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: [Could the meta site be more clearly labeled?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2841/could-the-meta-site-be-more-clearly-labeled)

Answer (score 2):

As J.R. said, you may have wandered into Meta English Language and Usage instead of the main site. At [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com), we discuss the English language. At Meta, we discuss the EL&U site. Yes, it's confusing. You probably want to go [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions).